# A Runnable that can be stopped - Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to create a runnable that can be stopped. *(CODE IS IN THE END)*

So I created a class  - `MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable implements Runnable`

1. This class maintains a variable `boolean running`, as long as this variable is `true`, the thread keeps running.
2. This class has `public synchronized boolean isRunning()` to check the whether thread is still running.
3. This class has `public synchronized boolean stopRunning()` which sets `running` to false which makes the thread stop.

This works fine but,

---

**I have few questions -**

**Q 1.** **Is the `synchronized` word needed in the methods if I create two diff `MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable` instances for two diff threads ?**

```
    MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable runn1 = new MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable();
    MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable runn2 = new MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runn1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runn2);
```

**Q 2.** **Is my `MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable` thread safe? Does the `boolean running` needs some modification?**

**Q 3. Can I create `MyThread extends Thread`, and this `MyThread` has a class variable of type `MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable`, so every time you want to stop the thread you do something like `MyThreadObj.getMyRunnableWhichIsStoppable().stopRunning()` ?**

---

**THIS IS MY CODE -**

```
public class Example3_AStoppableThread {

    public class MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable implements Runnable {

        boolean running;

        public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
            return running;
        }

        public synchronized boolean stopRunning() {
            if (running) {
                running = false;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void sleep(int time) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            running = true;
            System.out.println("About to run by Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            while (running) {
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +"-Running...");
            }
            System.out.println("I am stopped by Thread - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }

    public class Methods {
        public void process() {
            MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable runn1 = new MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable();
            MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable runn2 = new MyRunnableWhichIsStoppable();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(runn1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(runn2);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int k = sc.nextInt();
            if (k == 1) {
                System.out.println("Stopped ? "+runn1.stopRunning());
                System.out.println("Stopped ? "+runn2.stopRunning());
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example3_AStoppableThread p = new Example3_AStoppableThread();
        Methods m = p.new Methods();
        m.process();

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT -**

```
About to run by Thread - Thread-1
About to run by Thread - Thread-0
Thread-0-Running...
Thread-1-Running...
Thread-0-Running...
Thread-1-Running...
Thread-1-Running...
Thread-0-Running...
Thread-1-Running...
Thread-0-Running...
Thread-0-Running...
Thread-1-Running...
1
Stopped ? true
Stopped ? true
Thread-1-Running...
Thread-0-Running...
I am stopped by Thread - Thread-0
I am stopped by Thread - Thread-1
```

Comment: Why not just use an `AtomicInteger running`?

Comment: `boolean running;` should be marked as `volatile` or you should make use of something like `AtomicBoolean`, which will, otherwise, take care your just about all your concerns

Comment: `MyThread extends Thread` is not recommended. Q1. Using `synchronised` on a method will lock on the INSTANCE of the class only.  If you're trying to modify the state of `running` from potentially different threads, then yes, `synchronised` would be required (or you'd need an internal monitor lock or just make use of the `AtomicXxx` classes)

Comment: Also, beware that's it's possible for a thread to call `stopRunning` before `run` is called.  So you might need to consider that edge case somehow (assuming `running` to be `true` when the class is constructed maybe)

Comment: Interrupts already do all of this work.  Instead of implementing it yourself with a ‘running’ flag, just exit your run method when an InterruptedException occurs.

Comment: With your current implementation, set running with a synchronized setRunning method from run, plus use isRunning in run instead of direct access. As it is, your code is not thread safe. A volatile as suggested by MadProgrammer is easier.